# Enumerators Cast

Tags: objective-c, c

I have en error when try to cast own enumerator to address book values:

```
typedef enum {
    kACTextFirstName = kABPersonFirstNameProperty, // error: expression is not an integer constant expression
    kACTextLastName = (int)kABPersonLastNameProperty, // error: expression is not an integer constant expression
} ACFieldType;
```

How to solve the problem?

Thank you.

---

I need to init my enum using ABAddressBook's framework const values such as kABPersonLastNameProperty or kABPersonFirstNameProperty.

Comment: you should accept some answers ...

Comment: Did you import the proper headers?

Comment: What is `kABPersonFirstNameProperty`?

Comment: Where and how are `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` and `kABPersonLastNameProperty` declared?

Comment: @Keith: Apple header and `const uint32_t`, so your guess below was spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C (unlike in C++), an object declared `const`, even if it's initialized with a constant expression, cannot be used as a constant.

You didn't bother to show us the declaration of `kABPersonFirstNameProperty`, but I"m guessing it's declared something like:

```
const int kABPersonFirstNameProperty = 42;
```

If you need to use the name `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` as a constant expression, you can either declare it as a macro:

```
#define kABPersonFirstNameProperty 42
```

or as an enumeration constant:

```
enum { kABPersonFirstNameProperty = 42 };
```

Note that the enum hack only lets you declare constants of type `int`.

Likewise for `kABPersonLastNameProperty`.

(And why do you cast one of them to `int`, but not the other?)

If that doesn't answer your question, it's because you didn't give us enough information.